# Internal Trigger to Obtain Newly Inserted Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute a query but am having trouble. To start I have Table A and Table B.  Table A has the following columns (RowID, ItemNumber, CaseCount, Elc, TotalElc, TimeStamp). Table B has the following columns( RowID, ItemNumber, Elc, TotalElc)
I am using a dashboard to insert values into Table A. I am inserting integers into ItemNumber, and CaseCount.

When these values are inserted, I am using an internal trigger on Table A after any inserts that have been made. The internal trigger obtains the values that were just inserted and uses the ItemNumber to lookup Table B to obtain the ELC and Totallc and insert it into Table A where the ItemNumber matches Table B.

1. How to obtain the values with the trigger to retrieve the newly inserted values (values being ItemNumber, CaseCount)?
2. Then after the values are retrieved, how to use the item numbers(will be 20 ItemNumbers inserted at once) to look up values in table B and insert them into Table A where the ItemNumber matches?

I don’t  have much code since I am practically stuck on number  one . Any help is most appreciated.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ObtainValues 
   ON  Table A 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

Comment: If you already have the values with a relationship defined in Table B, why move the values at all?  You're duplicating data.

Comment: Table B has 14,000 rows. This is a production run. So I need the corresponding data from table B inserted into table A

Comment: That didn't explain why you want to keep multiple copies of the same data. Is there a reason to denormalize this?

Comment: how am I "denormalizing" it? What are you suggesting to do then. Its not multiple copies since Table A has a TimeStamp involved. Table B is generic and is used merely to get values from there and put them somewhere else. Its a production run. I am using other tables, graphs, charts, and gauges to monitor the performance for the production run according to the shift a.k.a timestamp. Does this explain more? Thanks for the help

Comment: You are creating multiple copies of your data. The values already exist TableB, why do you need to copy them into another table? Can you not reference the values in TableB? Why no simply insert a row into TableA with the ItemNumber and a TimeStamp (I would use a different name here since TimeStamp refers to something completely different).

Comment: I now see what you are saying. However, the dashboard builder I am using is Xcelcius. I am already executing 7 different queries at once referring to the same aspx page. The query is in Rockwell Factory Talk's Vantage point. This is not robust enough nor do I trust it to run queries that may take a while to execute. I prefer not to have conditions when inserting values from the dashboard as it may "bogg" down the system or make the other queries not execute. Thats why im inserting first and leaving the conditions to SQL on the databse side as opposed to the SCADA side

Comment: I know you still are wondering why make copies? Its important at the end of each shift, the operators manually inserts the item number and case count from the dashboard. Once this happens, SQL needs those values to cross reference with Table B so that report can be generated. If I am still not on your level of thinking, please be more clear and explain. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As you have created Trigger on Table A, whenever a row is insert, SQL Server will create a table called **INSERTED** which holds newly added rows only. The scope of this **INSERTED** table is within your Trigger body only.

Check the below code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ObtainValues 
   ON  Table A 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TableA 
    SET col1 = B.col1,
        col1 = B.col1
    FROM TableB B
    WHERE B.ItemNumber = (SELECT ItemNumber FROM INSERTED)

END
GO
```

Similarly, when delete event occurs, **DELETED** table is created.

Comment: This is not going to work. Your trigger assumes a single row insert. You need to handle this as a set. This could be modified to use inserted and it should produce what I understand the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Nithin's fine example as a starting point. I modified this so it will handle multiple row inserts.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ObtainValues 
   ON  TableA 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE TableA 
SET col1 = B.col1,
    col1 = B.col1
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A on a.[YourPrimaryKey] = b.[YourPrimaryKey]

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```